# How to set QLabel's size to that of the image in its pixmap?

Tags: c++, image, qt

I am using QT for my application, and ended up using QLabel to display image. However, it is displayed cropped.
How can the size of QLabel set to one of its pixmap? How can that be done in such a way that it would change if the pixmap changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// Call this function whenever you want to change the label's pixmap
void SetPixmapLabel(QLabel * myLabel, const QPixmap & pixmap)
{
   myLabel->setPixmap(pixmap);
   myLabel->setFixedSize(pixmap.size());
}
```