# QLabel Automatically resize QT

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

It's three days that I'm trying to solve an annoying problem with Qlabel e its dimension. I created a program to extract the coordinates with the mouse of some specific points inside the image. The image is loaded inside a Qlabel inside a Qscrollarea. the program works but there is an error with the coordinates due to the automatic resizing of the QLabel. 
The proprieties of Qlabel are: ScaleContent true and the verical and horizontal policies set to prefeered.

in the beginning I load the image with layout in this way:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->lbl_image_istruction->setScaledContents(true);
ui->txt_instruction->setText( "Please load the image you want to analyze" );

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();

layout->addWidget(ui->label_show);

ui->label_show->setScaledContents(true);
ui->scrollContent->setLayout(layout);
ui->label_show->installEventFilter(this);
```

I tried with a toy image of size 1000x1000. The progam loads correctly the image and the size of Qlabel is 1000x1000 but as soon as the program starts (I select the pixel inside the images) the dimension of QLabel changes to 982x982 generating an error with the selecion of the pixels. For instace the center of the image that should be 499x499 is 479x479.

It seems like the vertical and the horizontal scroolbar reduced the size of the image.

Does anyone have any idea about the problem? 
Probably it is a stupid question and it is very easy to solve but I'm not able to figure out a solution.

Another example.

```
void esempio::on_actionNormaleSize_triggered()
{
//---------------------------------------------------------
//     code to restore the original size of the image
//---------------------------------------------------------

imagesize = ui->label_show->size();
imagesize.rheight() = imagesize.rheight()*1/scaleFactor;
imagesize.rwidth() = imagesize.rwidth()*1/scaleFactor;

//restoring factor
scaleFactor =1;

ui->label_show->resize(imagesize);
ui->scrollContent->resize(imagesize);
}
```

By using the this function I want to restore the original size of the image. If the scale factor is 1 the size should stay constant but every time I call it the dimensions of my toy image reduce in this way. 1000x1000, 982x982, 964x964, 946x946, 928x928 and so on...

Thanks

Comment: do you use layouts? Show code! There is something called size policy.

Comment: Yes Mark I use a layout (plese see the modification of my questions). The all the code is very very long. The policies of scroll area, scroll content and Qlabel are set to prefeered

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851890/how-to-set-qlabels-size-to-that-of-the-image-in-its-pixmap/5851910#5851910

Comment: Thank Jeremy for the suggestion. But it partially solved the problem. In this way the image keep the same size but it seems that the horizontal and vertical scrollbar put on the top of the last colums and row of the image

Comment: You are mixing UI made in designer with Ui created by code in wrong way! Do not reparent widgets which are provided by designer. If you want do UI changes made by code create new widget. IMO if you use properly designer than you don't have to use any layout in code.

Comment: What do you means? I created all the objects with desinger

Comment: Yest but you are adding in code a layout and moving label created by designer to this layout. This is bad and bug prone.